# Usage of אמר מר and גופא

Tags: talmud-gemara, rabbis, language

The Gemora sometimes wants to discuss a side point from a previous text. It will introduce this as אמר מר or גופא for example the first page of Brachos says: אֲמַר מָר: ״מִשָּׁעָה שֶׁהַכֹּהֲנִים נִכְנָסִים לֶאֱכוֹל בִּתְרוּמָתָן״, מִכְּדִי, כֹּהֲנִים, אֵימַת קָא אָכְלִי תְּרוּמָה?

we use the word אמר מר in order to bring up a side point that was mentioned.

or גופא that seems to do the same thing for example
גּוּפָא: אֲמַר רִבִּי תַּנְחוּם אֲמַר רַב אַסֵי: טָעָה וְלֹא הִזְכִּיר גְּבוּרוֹת גְּשָׁמִים בִּתְחִיַּית הַמֵּתִים, מַחֲזִירִין אוֹתוֹ;

it goes back to a previous mention

why sometimes does it use אמר מר and sometimes גופא? Is there a rule?
The answer must include a source

Comment: Thank you my question is what is the difference between Amar mar and gufa
This only answers what mar is referring to

Comment: @fulltimekollelguy can you give examples? It would help as I'm struggling to think of situations where those two phrases mean the same thing

Comment: @fulltimekollelguy yes. I mean that your question is solved in the answer. Gufa is when they come back to the Berayta regerding an other issue and Amar Mar is coming badk to the main issue.

Comment: @kouty you are right although my question is not a duplicate. this source https://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=17713 based on the shalah answers it
Thank you!